# Symfony Cannot run recipes:update

Tags: symfony

Following instructions for Symfony framework, Upgrading a Major Version.  The third step is Updating Recipes.  When I attempt it, the following error is generated.

```
/var/www/project$ composer recipes:update
  Cannot run recipes:update: Your git index contains uncommitted changes.
  Please commit or stash them and try again!
```

I couldn't find the exact message in Google.  And I'm not using git at all.  Why would I need to commit changes to git if it's not even set up?

Comment: Well symfony new will setup git as long as the executable is on your system.  So even if you never used it you could still have a bunch of uncommited changes.  Does `git status` show a bunch of stuff or just git not found?

Comment: @Cerad `git log` shows 2 commits from January, created 19 seconds apart.  I'm guessing I didn't make those.  It's strange that the documentation doesn't mention any of this.

Comment: I'm still not understanding this.  I created a new commit, and recipes:update ran for a single recipe, told me no files were changed, and now I can't run it again due to the same error message.

Comment: Well to be honest I don't use the recipe update.  Letting something update my application stuff gives me the willies.  I usually just create a new app for the new version and just sort of look it over to see what has changed.  I see you opened a discussion topic.  Maybe you will have better luck there.

Comment: For now, I manually created a new commit for every pending recipe update.  It just doesn't seem like that much work should be needed.